# squarespace local development issue

Tags: java, windows, npm, squarespace

I cloned the git repo for the Square Space site downloaded Node version 11.10.0 and also have java version 10.0.2 installed. I used the npm to download the Square space local development server however when I start the server giving it my website URL I am getting a Java exception any idea what could cause this issue? Here is what the exception looks like. Any help would be appreciated.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tU2P.png)

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace, not the picture

Comment: What operating system and version are you running?

Comment: What template are you using?

Comment: Here is the Stack Trace

Comment: C:\Projects\ChessMates_Project\Website\template>squarespace-server https://cardioid-duck-b35w.squarespace.com
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.getJavaRelease(Version.java:36)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:106)
        at

Comment: org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createSpecializedConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createSpecializedConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:24)

Comment: at javax.validation.Validation$ProviderSpecificBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:220)
        at io.dropwizard.validation.BaseValidator.newConfiguration(BaseValidator.java:28)
        at io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.Validators.newConfiguration(Validators.java:35)
        at io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.Validators.newValidatorFactory(Validators.java:27)
        at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:68)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)
        at com.squarespace.developer.DevelopmentServer.main(DevelopmentServer.java:53)

Comment: The operating system is Windows 10 Professional

Comment: The template is by squarespace it is a simple template with some basic links like home , about and a page for events which is empty at the moment